# Finding minimum traveling wave solutions to Fisher's equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Given Fisher's equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dz}&=S,\\
\frac{\mathrm dS}{\mathrm dz}&=-\frac{\alpha}{D}P(1-P)-\frac{v}{D}S.
\end{align*}

How would you estimate the minimum wave speed?

I have performed stability analyses on these two equations and I concluded that steady state $(P,S) = (0,0)$ would be a stable node and $(1,0)$ must be a saddle in order to give rise to a traveling wave.

I'm not entirely sure how to approach the minimum wave speed from here. Do I take the derivative in terms of $v$ somehow in the second equation?

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian and note that the wave speed must be real. Also, should the second equation be $dS/dz$?

Comment: Got it after thinking about it for a bit. Yes, the second equation should be $dS/dz$ as well. Just realized that I have to use the necessary conditions (as you said build the proper eigenvalues)